# webClient.DownloadFile() return 404

Tags: c#, asp.net, http-status-code-404, webclient

browser download file with this url ok, but webClient return 404

```
 string url = "http://zakupki.gov.ru/44fz/filestore/public/1.0/download/priz/file.html?uid=19CC93BEA67C4650B51D69CAA28CB27D";      
 using (var webClient = new WebClient())
        {                          
            webClient.DownloadFile(url , "name");
        }
```

Comment: Maybe you need to set the UserAgent.

Comment: [C# Webclient returning error 404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44971530/c-sharp-webclient-returning-error-404) will probably help you. View the response if you can.

Comment: It's a Word Document (.docx) written in Russian. Is it something relevant to you? Because it's public now. The User-Agent header suggestion is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the difference between the request done by the Web Browser and the request form the WebClient.

You need to add this to your code:

```
webClient.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)");
```

So your code will be changed to this:

```
string url = "http://zakupki.gov.ru/44fz/filestore/public/1.0/download/priz/file.html?uid=19CC93BEA67C4650B51D69CAA28CB27D";
using (var webClient = new WebClient())
{
  webClient.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)");
  webClient.DownloadFile(url, "name.docx");
}
```

I hope it helps you

Comment: A minor suggestion: instead of hardcoding the string it would be more semantically correct (although ultimately it shouldn't really matter) to use the actual values, i.e. `$"Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; {Environment.OSVersion.VersionString}; .NET CLR {Environment.Version};)"`.